# Character (string) encoded number to number comparison in Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have this query.

```
  levelnumber = (from b in bv.baLevels
                 where b.ba_Level_Code == ("0" + SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double)cl.Level_Num.Value)) && b.isActive == 1
                 select (b.ba_Level_Code + " - " + b.ba_Level_Desc)).FirstOrDefault(),
```

My Problem is b.ba_Level_Code is string.

cl.Level_Num is Int.

baLevels table I have this ba_Level_code value has 008

but cl is the BaCodeLibrary table this cl.Level_Num has 8

if I do the query with hardcoded value

```
 levelnumber = (from b in bv.baLevels
                where b.ba_Level_Code == "008" && b.isActive == 1
                select (b.ba_Level_Code + " - " + b.ba_Level_Desc)).FirstOrDefault(),
```

how to display 008? cl.Level_Num I am getting has 8. I need to change that value to 008.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `string.Format` to specify that your `cl.Level_Num' is converted to a string with a minimum number of digits:

```
string.Format("{0:D3}", cl.Level_Num.Value) // would ouput "008" value 8
```

Thus:

```
levelnumber = (from b in bv.baLevels
               where b.ba_Level_Code == string.Format("{0:D3}", cl.Level_Num.Value) && b.isActive == 1
               select (b.ba_Level_Code + " - " + b.ba_Level_Desc)).FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Thanks Jeffora, but I have some other level Number in the table has 046,023,056.....etc.. I think I will get problem that time.

Comment: I am getting this error.LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @user957178 looks like you have to cast the 2nd parameter to a type.

Comment: Just FYI the String.Format call would work in those situations too (in terms of formatting - D3 means minimum 3 digits so will put in leading zeros if required). As for the Linq To Entities problem, it sounds like a pain to get around and I agree with adrift's recommendation

Answer (score 2):

I can't see a good way to do this in LINQ to Enties.  Assuming that you cannot modify the data type of the `ba_Level_Code` column, I think your best option is to add a persisted [computed column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250.aspx) to that table, index it, and use that column in your query.

For example, if you defined a column

```
ba_Level_Code_Int as (case when isnumeric(ba_Level_Code)= 1 then cast(ba_Level_Code as int) end) persisted
```

then your LINQ query could be

```
levelnumber = (from b in bv.baLevels   
               where b.ba_Level_Code_Int == cl.Level_Num.Value && b.isActive == 1   
               select (b.ba_Level_Code + " - " + b.ba_Level_Desc)).FirstOrDefault();
```